# ! Can't convert `x` <iv<integer>> to <character> in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a CSV file from the output of grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

df_1 %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = iv_overlaps(iv(start, end)))

write.csv(df_1 , "Test.csv",quote = F, row.names = F)
```

However, I get the error in `as.character()`:

```
! Can't convert `x` <iv\<integer>> to \<character>.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What packages are you using? Where does `iv_overlaps` come from?

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly as you have not provided a reproducible example or told us what packages you are using, but something that stands out is that you have not assigned the results of your pipe to anything - try `df_1 <- df_1 %>%` at the start.